# importing function from using path rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I would like to attempt to dynamically import some stuff based on the file name.
In short the user will type in a name off the command and I want to search `./commands` dir for the file that has the same name as the command and if any files do match I want to run `fn execute` in them.

However I'm currently stuck here.

```rs
// main.rs
let paths_to_commands = std::fs::read_dir("./src/commands").unwrap();
for path in paths_to_commands {
    let temp = path.unwrap().path().read_dir();
}
```

I have no problems creating an if statement that will check the file name however Im not sure how do I run the `execute` function can anyone help me out because I didn't really found any information on this topic.

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to run `fn execute` on some file"? Do you want to find an _executable_ file by name and then execute it if one is found?

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of files in commands dir and each file has `pub fn execute` in it that I want to run @AleksanderKrauze

Comment: @Laycookie: you mean `./commands` contains `.rs` files? Rust is a compiled language.
You shouldn't treat it like an interpreter.

Comment: Ohh sorry I'm just so used to doing this in typescript that I forgot that you can't do it in a compiled language lol. Is there any other method to achive what I want without just having a massive match statment? @ChrisB

Comment: No problem :). Without knowing your usecase too well, I would probably suggest using 
a `trait Comand {  fn execute(); }`, then implement that trait for all your commands.
You could then have a `Vec<Box<dyn Command>>` containing all your commands.
You might also get away with just using a `Vec<Box<dyn Fn()>>` instead of the trait, but as I said I don't know your usecase.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying but how would I push my commands to that vec from all of the files in my command dir? Wouldn't I still have to have a giant import statement and a bunch of arr.push() in the main.rs? @ChrisB

Comment: This question seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, so It's probably best to delete / significantly edit it. If you *really* wanted to do what the question asks about, 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177318/is-there-a-rust-interpreter) would be a starting point.

Comment: @Laycookie: Yes, you have to import files that you are using. That's life :).

Comment: Ya I was already thinking about editing the question, just wanted to make sure I first understood in what direction I was pivoting. Also didn't know there was a rust interpreter thank you for that information.
I will probably investigate both methods of solving this problem a little more and then come back with an edit and what solution I came up with. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "use" or import a local Rust file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file)

Comment: @bug No, you could use that approach to solve my problem but this specific question is asking about "dynamically importing" functions.